# How can we avoid 'are the same file' warning message when using 'cp' in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, cp

I'm trying to copy certain files from one directory to another. Using this command

```
find "$HOME" -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t $HOME/newdir
```

I get an warning message saying

> cp: '/home/me/newdir/logfile.txt' and '/home/me/newdir/logfile.txt'
> are the same file

How can I avoid this warning message?

Comment: `your_command 2>/dev/null` =)

Comment: Yes, this works but not quite the solution I was looking for :-) With this I get a rid of this warning but cannot avoid it still

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that you try to copy a file to itself. You can avoid it by excluding the destination directory from the results of the *find* command like this:

```
find "$HOME" -name '*.txt' -type f -not -path "$HOME/newdir/*" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t "$HOME/newdir"
```

Comment: Thanks but this generates the same warning in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `install` instead. This replaces by removing the file first.

```
install -v target/release/dynnsd-client target/
```

Output:

```
removed 'target/dynnsd-client'
'target/release/dynnsd-client' -> 'target/dynnsd-client'
```

And then remove the source files.

Answer (score 1):

Make it unique in the process. But this require sorting

```
find "$HOME" -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | sort -zu | xargs -0 cp -t "$HOME/newdir"
```

Or if it's not about the generated files, try to use the `-u` option of `cp`.

```
find "$HOME" -name '*.txt' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -ut "$HOME/newdir"
```

```
-u   copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when
     the destination file is missing
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of these solutions generate the same warning message in Ubuntu bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) instead of [cp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_(Unix)):

```
find "$HOME" -name "*.txt" -exec rsync {} "$HOME"/newdir \;
```

Comment: rsync worked, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Install

It worked perfectly in a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile) context with [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29):

```
copy:
    @echo ''
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/shell                   .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/docker-compose.yml      .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/statoshi                .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/gui                     .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/$(DOCKERFILE)           .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/$(DOCKERFILE_SLIM)      .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/$(DOCKERFILE_GUI)       .'
    bash -c 'install -v ./docker/$(DOCKERFILE_EXTRACT)   .'
    @echo ''

build-shell: copy
    docker-compose build shell
```